# IMO 1998 - Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

I am trying this IMO Combinatorics problem $1998$ P2 that goes like this:

> In a competition, there are $m$ contestants and $n$ judges, where $n \geq 3$ is an odd integer. Each judge rates each contestant as either “pass” or “fail”. Suppose $k$ is a number such that, for any two judges, their ratings coincide for at most $k$ contestants. Prove that $$\frac{k}{m}\geq \frac{n-1}{2n}$$

I am completely puzzled on how to start, could you give me any hints?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  You'll find you get a lot better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: I would be very surprised if there were no AoPS thread on this problem...

Comment: I remember that problem. I think it's beautiful problem. When I solving that problem I though in a algebraic proof, but in that moment I couldn't complete the proof.

Comment: @user125932 in my first edition, I found the variables $a,b$; but only I edited with MathJax.

Comment: A standard technique to attack such problems is to construct an "adjacency" matrix and double counting some quantity row and column wise. This often gives both upper and lower bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the number of combinations $(\{j_1, j_2\},c)$,  where $\{j_1, j_2\}$ is a pair of distinct judges, and $c$ is a contestant that they agree on.  You can arrive at this quantity two ways:

1. Sum over contestants, the number of pairs of judges who agree on them.
2. Sum over pairs of judges, the number of contestants they agree on.

Then the quantity being summed in 1. can be bounded below by an expression involving $n$ (remember $n$ is odd), whilst the quantity being summed in 2. may be bounded above by $k$.  Combining yields the desired inequality.